# SQLGrammarException: Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database (SQL-Server colllation Latin1_General_BIN)

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, hibernate, jdbc, rapidclipse

I've created a new Persistence Unit in RapidClipse (Eclipse Neon with Hibernate [and other] plugins included) using a new connection profile to an SQL-Server 2014. "Test connection" works fine - "Ping succeeded!".

The next dialog "Generate Entities from Tables -> Select tables" shows all tables, but on choosing one and using "Generate Entities from Tables -> Table Associations" fails:

[image: Hibernate metadata on BIN collation]

This does only happen when using a case sensitive collation - the database uses "Latin1_General_BIN", if I switch it to "Latin1_General_CI_AS" hibernate doesn't show any problems with the identity strategies but I cannot change the database collation on the production server.

**Question**: Is there a way to fix the "Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database." error without changing the collation?

Stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem. 
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.SQLServerMetaDataDialect.getSuggestedPrimaryKeyStrategyName(SQLServerMetaDataDialect.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.PrimaryKeyProcessor.processPrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyProcessor.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCBinder.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinder.readFromDatabase(JDBCBinder.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.readFromJDBC(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractConfigurationFacade.readFromJDBC(AbstractConfigurationFacade.java:208)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.hibernate.metadata.MetadataUtils.lambda$1(MetadataUtils.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.hibernate.metadata.MetadataUtils.readDatabaseMetadata(MetadataUtils.java:146)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.server.core.ui.wizard.generateentities.AssociationsWizardPage.init(AssociationsWizardPage.java:849)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.server.core.ui.wizard.generateentities.AssociationsWizardPage.lambda$2(AssociationsWizardPage.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.server.core.ui.wizard.generateentities.AssociationsWizardPage.lambda$3(AssociationsWizardPage.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ungültiger Objektname 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1522)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1716)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.SQLServerMetaDataDialect.getSuggestedPrimaryKeyStrategyName(SQLServerMetaDataDialect.java:36)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite self-explanatory: *Probably a JDBC driver problem*.

You may want to check if there's an updated driver.

Apart from this, I cannot see the reason why you want to generate entities **from** production db, istead of **using** production (altered) schema (only for generation!).

You can just

1. export'n'import the production db (just the schema if it's a big one) in development environment
2. change the collation in dev-env
3. generate entities
4. revert collation / re-import (**in dev-env**, so you can test your new entities)
5. it should work fine (**even in production**, without any db modification) when you'll deploy your app

Since the error is related to `Ungültiger Objektname 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns'`, which is used only by generation procedure, doing this way it's probably the best-effort solution.

If it's not working even this way, then it's not related to *Eclipse*/*RapidClipse*, but it's a real compatibility problem between Hibernate and the JDBC driver.

In this case, maybe there's some specific hibernate/jdbc configuration parameter to handle binary collation (maybe a specific *dialect*).

Comment: Thank you for the answer - the problem occurs both with the "shipped" JDBC driver and with the most current from MS download page :-(
The reason for "not altering the production database": it is used with different applications too which expect the collation the DB currently is in.

Comment: I didn't mean to alter the production db, just **temporary** alter the dev copy, only the time necessary to generate the entities, then revert to the original collation. Production db is left untouched.